# Use boost::interprocess::mutex to synchronize shared memory access

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, interprocess, boost-mutex

I am having two different applications developed in `C++`. These applications communicate each other via `boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object`. Now I require a `mutex` variable to sync the operations between the two.. Can somebody provide a minimal example for this. The code of my applications is as follows:

App A:

```
    boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object shm (boost::interprocess::create_only, "MySharedMemory", boost::interprocess::read_write);
    shm.truncate (1024);
    boost::interprocess::mapped_region region(shm,boost::interprocess::read_write);

   std::strcpy(static_cast<char* >(region.get_address()), "WRITE\n");

/*I need to write some data to shared memory here. But line by line.     i.e., I write first line. App B reads it. Then I write second line. For this i require mutex*/
```

App B:

```
    boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object shm (boost::interprocess::open_only, "MySharedMemory", boost::interprocess::read_write);
    boost::interprocess::mapped_region region (shm, boost::interprocess::read_write);

    char *str1 = static_cast<char*> (region.get_address());
    char subbuff[5];
    memcpy( subbuff, str1, 5 );
    subbuff[5] = '\0';
    while(strcmp(subbuff,"WRITE")!=0)
    {
        str1 = static_cast<char*> (region.get_address());
        memcpy( subbuff, str1, 5 );
        subbuff[5] = '\0';
    }

/*Here I want  to read the data written by App A line by line*/
```

Comment: Is there no sample in the documentation?

Comment: @sehe: not in case of unrelated processes